# Server-sided timestamp with AWS DynamoDB V2 when using an IoT Core Action?

Tags: amazon-web-services, timestamp, amazon-dynamodb, aws-iot

I'm currently using the IoT Core action to store some JSON Data in a DynamoDB table. Everything works fine, the only problem is, that everything is stored in one column (*payload* in my case).
I found out that when using the *DynamoDB V2 action* every Key-Value pair of my JSON input will be stored in a separat column. I was also able to implement this.

But now I have the problem that I'm not able anymore to create the timestamp column which could be defined when using DynamoDB V1. There I could just say that my secondary key is a timestamp and with the function `timestamp()` it will automatically create a server-sided timestamp of each input. 
As there is no option like this when using the Version 2 I was wondering if there is a way to add a column with a timestamp to input that comes through the IoT Core MQTT gateway?

I think I could go the lambda-path and trigger a function which writes each input to the V2 to DynamoDB but I try to avoid this as I will have a huge amount of data coming through.

If you have any thoughts or ideas I would be pleased to hear them.

Cheers,

Comment: This 3-minute video shows how we accomplished that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQkiF3AeKfs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can already be done with the DynamoDB V2 action by using the `SELECT` clause of the IoT rule.

The keys that it uses when writing to DynamoDB can come from the payload and/or the `SELECT` Clause of the IoT rule. So the `timestamp()` function can be used to automatically create a server-side timestamp.

e.g. setup a rule such as:

```
SELECT *, timestamp() AS Timestamp FROM 'mytopic/#'
```

The DynamoDB V2 action writes into a table with the primary key:

```
Primary partition key    Id (String)
Primary sort key         Timestamp (Number)
```

In this example the `Id` field comes from the payload and is the partition key. The `timestamp()` function is the server-side timestamp that is the sort key.

So publishing to a topic with this payload:

```
{
  "message": "Hello from AWS IoT console",
  "value": "101",
  "Id": "2"
}
```

Will create items using the `Id` in the payload and the `Timestamp` from the `timestamp()` function.

[image]